# Oracle apex, selecting item from dropdown causes infinite buffering

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created a list of values in shared components, using the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(First_Name, Last_Name) as display_value, 
Customer_ID as return_value
FROM tbl_Customer;
```

However, on opening the form and selecting an item from the dropdown,multiple buffering icons appear next to the field and it becomes unusable. I have also entered the query manually, rather than using a shared component which gave the same result, and I am lost on what to try next. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

[image: buffering]

Testing the query on its own, it finds the display and return values as expected
[image: standalone query]

Edit:

After checking the debug menu, I am seeing this:

[image: ajax plugins]
The query seems to be executing but something is going wrong, yet not sending an error code.
[image: ajax details]

Edit 2: Once again I have edited the query to improve the spacing and make the display value less ambiguous and the same issue is still occuring, which makes me wonder if this is an issue with apex rather than a code fault as the query executes perfectly on its own.

```
SELECT (Customer_ID || ' ' || First_Name || ' ' || Last_name) as display_value, 
Customer_ID as return_value
FROM tbl_Customer;
```

Comment: How big is `tbl_Customer`?  If that has thousands of rows, you're probably better with some other type of control like a text field with autocomplete.

Comment: There are currently only 6 rows in the table, and it will probably stay that way. I should add that the names of each customer displays in the dropdown but disappear when trying to select anything other than the default value, which allows submission of the form, but the Customer_ID is set to null in the record.

Comment: Is there some other widget that depends on customer id and refreshes when a selection is made? That icon usually appears when a round trip is happening between the page and Oracle, so run the page in debug mode and check out the debug log for an Ajax action.

Comment: Could there be a dynamic action on the page item that has this list of values, or is this page item referenced in another dynamic action ?

Comment: This page is not currently referenced anywhere as it is only the second page of the application so far, I've checked out the debug and there seems to be a lot of Ajax actions being executed, but they all seem to be almost identical as far as I can see, updating the post now