# Oracle apex filling form from shared component LOV

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a query written to fetch some concatenated values as a display value, and the ID of a customer as the return value, however, the display value only shows the first part of the display value, and on clicking any of the options, buffering icons appear next to the field and continue infinitely.

[image: infinite buffering]

```
SELECT (Customer_ID || ' ' || First_Name || ' ' || Last_name) as display_value, 
Customer_ID  as return_value
FROM tbl_Customer;
```

This query works perfectly when run on its own, and I have used something similar for another table, which also works, both in theory and in actual use

```
SELECT Customer_ID  d, 
License_Plate  r
FROM tbl_Vehicle;
```

I've tested the original query in as many different ways as I can think of, including making it almost identical to to the formatting/syntax of the second query and the issue still persits.

Comment: The SQL statement looks fine (assuming `tbl_customer` is still relatively small).  This appears to be highly related to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550079/oracle-apex-selecting-item-from-dropdown-causes-infinite-buffering where your latest updates seem to indicate that the problem is some AJAX call on the page.  I can't read the image of the log that you posted, though.

Comment: That image is just showing the buffering problem it's resulting in, and yeah the table is only 5 or 6 records, and like I said the query itself works fine on its own, so it definitely seems to be some kind of AJAX call related problem, but I'm not really sure where to begin with it

Comment: The image I'm talking about is the image of the debug log.  Personally, I'd start a new page and build it up slowly to see at what point the problem occurs.  Can you reproduce the issue on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: Oh I see about the image, I'll copy the code into this post in an edit if it helps, and everything I've done so far has been online rather than the app.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it again, no error or anything is being sent from the form, all the ajax timestamps are from 4 days ago, but I can't get anything new to appear

Comment: The image shows multiple reloading icons. It looks like you have dynamic actions on the item. Can you please check any dynamic actions on the item or its parent if it is cascading? Also, please check if fire on initialization is yes on the dynamic action.